# Does anyone know any magnetic connectors?

Tags: lighting

I'm trying to build a gadget with LED lights. The odea is to have separate pieces of lights which can be combined together and can be played around as LEGO. I would like for each piece to be joined with another piece with magnets and that those magnets have a connector of some kind. This will allow me to programmatically know which pieces are connected and make one bigger piece.
So, the question is if there are some kind of IoT magnetic connectors?

Comment: You could place regular magnets anywhere in your case (probably in the corners, really, to ensure better stability), and use Pogo pins as connectors. How many wires do you need? What signals will you carry? How much power? Are there orientation issues?

Comment: Aliexpress yields this: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000364190719.html

Comment: have you actually googled the connectors? ... your question has nothing to do with IoT really ... it is an electronics question ... the term `IoT connector` does not make much sense

Comment: I'm actually new to this, so I might have misused the terms. I know what IoT is, and I agree that this is an electronics problem. But I'm looking for a managed and programmable device that can be combined togheter to test the approach. It does not have to be production ready, just a PoC. The thing is, that I didn't know where to start, but I know what I want. Any help appriciated.